# Is it possible to block a wifi network by viewing its radio channels and causing interference on them?

Tags: wireless-networking

Is it possible to block a wifi network by viewing its radio channels and causing interference on them ?

Obviously this would cause all network on that channel to be blocked also. And all the network manager would need to do would be to change to another channel.

Comment: If you could, it would be *highly* illegal. And require ownership of devices that your local telecommunications testing agency would take a *very* dim view of.

Comment: To clarify im not looking to do this, or suggesting any one should. But in principal is it possible. Regarding the downvote, i think that it is un warrented as its a valid question related to WIFI / RF networking.